# Distributing software on Linux?

Tags: linux

I've been distributing my Python software on Linux by zipping a .py file and a .png with the icon. I feel this must be one of the worst ways to do it. Is there a sort of "application bundle" for Linux, equivalent to .app on Mac, and .exe on Windows? A single file the user can put somewhere and double-click to run without a terminal?

Comment: Search `writting egg files python modules` on google ;)

Comment: Should have made that an answer :)

Comment: answer shouldn't only links here.

Comment: Look into Linux package managers. The main ones are Debian (.deb) and Readhat (.rpm).]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to sputnik's comment: [A Small Introduction to Python Eggs](http://mrtopf.de/blog/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/).